# Bash case match trouble with mixed numbers and letters

Tags: bash, scripts, regex

I am trying to allow a user to enter in a size that will be used in `fallocate`, so I need to make sure text is entered as 1G, 8G, 512M, etc..

I have the following code below; however, all correct formats go to the default `*` case.

```
echo -n "What amount do you want to allocate to the new swapfile? [i.e. 4G or 512M]\n"
read size
echo $size
case $size in

    [1-9][0-9]*[m|M|g|G] )
        echo "Size Verified: $size"
        ;;

    *) 
        echo "Invalid size: $size. Please use the format 1-999[M|G]. 
        ;;
esac
```

I have checked my regex with https://regexr.com/ using the following `([1-9][0-9]*[m|M|g|G])`

Note: I know my warning message is more restrictive than my regex. Also, I am very new to bash. Please provide extra links I can research if the technique is advanced.

Comment: Just as a FYI, I plan on possibly changing it to allow for other lengths of units. i.e. GB, gb, giga, gigabyte, etc... But I am not certain, yet.

Comment: Shell globs are not regular expressions... in particular, if you are expecting `[0-9]*` to match zero or more decimal digits, it won't (it will match *one* decimal digit, followed by zero or more additional characters)

Comment: @steeldriver what my "glob" (??) is trying to do is the following. 1. Match a single digit 1-9 followed by any number of digits (0-9) followed by a single letter (M, G, m, or g). This disallows entering in `0G` or `0M`

Comment: Is this suppose to be correct then? `[1-9]*[0-9][m|M|g|G]`. I tried it but it fails, but does it fix that one issue? My test is to allow the following `8G` for 8GB. Once this passes, I will try other examples

Comment: No, that would still need two digits (with optional characters in between). AFAIK you will either need to test for different numbers of digits separately, or turn on extended globbing (`shopt -s extglob`) so that you can use `*([0-9])[mMgG]`

Comment: @steeldriver can `*([0-9])[mMgG]` be used in case statements? I get error messages that disappear when I remove the parentheses. Since a `)` is required for a case statement

Comment: I'll try quoting it later on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `case` uses shell globs - which are different from regular expressions. In particular, `*` (and `?`) are wildcard matches in themselves rather than quantifiers that affect the previous atom. So for example:

- basic regex:

  ```
  [0-9]? means 0 or 1 decimal digit
  [0-9]* means 0 or more decimal digits
  ```
- simple glob

  ```
  [0-9]? means a decimal digit followed by any single character
  [0-9]* means a decimal digit followed by any number of characters (including none)
  ```

As far as I know, there is no way to specify an arbitrary number of repeats in a simple shell glob. You have a number of options:

1. using simple shell globs, match each sequence explicitly and OR them together. For 1-3 digits for example,

   ```
   case $1 in
     [0-9][mMgG]|[0-9][0-9][mMgG]|[0-9][0-9][0-9][mMgG])
       echo "simple glob match"
     ;;
     *)
       echo "no simple glob match"
     ;;
   esac
   ```
2. use a bash *extended glob*, either `[0-9]*([0-9])` (one digit followed by zero or more digits - similar to your regular expression) or `+([0-9])` (one or more digits). *Note that unlike regexes, the quantifier comes before the atom, rather than after*.

   ```
   shopt -s extglob

   case $1 in
     +([0-9])[mMgG])
       echo "extended glob match"
     ;;
     *)
       echo "no extended glob match"
     ;;
   esac
   ```
3. use a bash regular expression, but within a `if` ... `then` conditional

   ```
   if [[ $1 =~ [0-9][0-9]*[mMgG] ]]; then
     echo "regex match"
   else
     echo "no regex match"
   fi
   ```

In the last case, you could also use short-circuit logic:

```
[[ $1 =~ [0-9][0-9]*[mMgG] ]] && echo "regex match" || echo "no regex match"
```

Also note that in both globs and regexes, `[...]` is a set of characters not an expression so `[m|M|g|G]` is no different from `[mMgG|]` and matches the literal characters `m`, `M`, `g`, `G` and `|` (probably not what you want).

Comment: I am using option #3; however, I noticed that you thought I wanted `[0-9][0-9]*[mMgG]`, but I wanted `[1-9][0-9]*[mMgG]`. With option 3 I know how to fix that, I don't know how to fix it for #2

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski apologies, I missed that. For the extended glob case, you would want to fall back to doing it in two parts i.e. `[1-9]*([0-9])`

Comment: ah, I understand your `[mMgG|]` comment now. I have removed all pipes

Comment: It's weird, I must have had some other small mistake, because that didn't work before. I will try that later on if I need it, thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski did you remember to add `shopt -s extglob` to your script? the extended syntax is disabled by default in non-interactive shells iirc

Comment: yes, I did, I also added `shopt -u extglob` at the very end of the script.  I think I had an error with the general syntax and that was causing the error